# HTML5 – это отдельный язык?

Tags: html5

Пересмотрел кучу статей в интернете и как мне кажется, так до конца и не понимаю, что такое HTML5 и CSS3. Понимаю, что такое HTML4 и CSS2 - грубо говоря, набор тегов, который был актуален пару лет назад.

Так вот, что я не понимаю: вроде как в версии HTML5 были добавлены новые теги, т.е. HTML5 – это только дополнительные теги? Потому что какие-то теги были убраны, какие-то добавлены, например, тот же `div`, `span`. Они же теперь в HTML5?

Часто слышал выражение, сделано на HTML5. И как понять сделано на HTML4 или на HTML5, если использовался `div` и `span`? Есть ли полный список тегов для HTML5?

И еще я где-то слышал, что уже давно нет разделения HTML5, есть просто HTML, это типа как был бред, вроде как язык-то один. Раньше говорили, чтобы писать на HTML5, надо прописать `doctype html`. Хотя я честно говоря этого не понимаю, вроде браузеры уже давно не обращают внимания на переходной `doctype`.

Comment: Прочитал повнимательнее стандарт. Как я понял понятия css3 и не существует. Походу кто-то его придумал, чтобы путать людей. Есть отдельные модули без привязки к номеру css 1) CSS Color Level 3 2) CSS Namespaces 3) Selectors Level 3 4) Media Queries 5) CSS Style Attributes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HTML5, к сожалению, применяется в нескольких значениях, поэтому "чтение кучи статей" вас скорее ещё сильнее запутало.

Есть HTML версии 5 как **язык разметки**, документ написанный на этом языке должен быть обозначен `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Тогда браузер считает, что для его интепретации надо использовать соответствующий стандарт. Да, на практике стандарт можно не соблюдать, но в таком случае работа в HTML5-совместимых браузерах **не гарантируется**. (В этом суть практически всех стандартов: либо соблюдаешь, либо не рассчитываешь на него.)

Можно не использовать ни одной новой фичи HTML5 по сравнению предыдущими версиями, но если доктайп правильный и стандарт соблюдён, то формально это HTML5.

**Часто HTML5 употребляется в значении "набор технологий"**, который был реализован в браузерах только с приходом HTML5. К примеру, элемент `<canvas>` и Canvas API дал возможность рисовать произвольную точечную графику, открыв новые горизонты играм для браузеров; чтобы этот элемент можно было употреблять в документах на HTML5, язык разметки должен это предусматривать.

Как узнать версию? Формально, по `DOCTYPE`. Да, браузер часто способен понять и неправильный, но это **не гарантируется** и это не повод стандарт нарушать. *Фактически сайт может не соблюдать **ни один** стандарт и при этом работать.*

Answer (score 15):

Если раньше HTML4 был просто языком разметки веб-страниц, то HTML5 помимо этого получил ещё и возможности для создания полноценных Web-приложений.

Список этих новых и не очень возможностей:

- Семантика: позволяет точнее описывать, что из себя представляет ваша страница.
- Связь: новые способы общения с сервером.
- Оффлайн и Хранилище: способы, позволяющие сохранять данные на стороне пользователя (обзорщика).
- Мультимедиа: создание и взаимодействие с видео и звуком.
- 2D/3D Графика и эффекты.
- Доступ к устройствам: использование разных устройств для ввода и вывода данных.
- Внешний вид: создание более новых образов.

Так что одним doctype и парой новых html-меток дело не ограничено. Подробнее же можно прочитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/HTML/HTML5).